# Java: Find and Replace a line

Tags: java, replace

I have seen many posts regarding this, but I'm not able to do this. I need to do something like this ..Lets say,
I have two files a.txt, b.txt.
I should search for a string/line in a.txt and replace it with the content of b.txt.
I think its jus few lines of simple code. I tried the below code but its not working ...

```
File func = new File("a.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(func));

String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.matches("line to replace")) {
        br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(func));
        StringBuffer whole = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            whole.append(line.toString() + "\r\n");
        }
        whole.toString().replace("line to replace",
                "b.txt content");
        br.close();

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(func);
        writer.write(whole.toString());
        writer.close();
        break;
    }
}
br.close();
```

Please help !

Comment: `writer.close();` and `br.close();` should be outside the while loop. Plus, you should create `writer` and `br` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a technique to solve this problem:

1. Open the a.txt file for reading.
2. Open the b.txt file for reading.
3. Open an output file named a.new.txt.
4. Read one line from the a.txt file.
5. If the line is not the desired line (the line to replace), write the line to the output file then goto step 4.
6. Append the contents of the b.txt file to the output file.
7. Append the remaining contents of a.txt to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... maybe you can avoid creating instances of BufferedReader classes and work just with the String classes:

```
public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    File afile = new File("/home/mtataje/a.txt");

    String aContent = getFileContent(afile);
    System.out.println("A content: " );
    System.out.println(aContent);
    System.out.println("===================");
    if (aContent.contains("java rulez")) {
        File bfile = new File("/home/mtataje/b.txt");
        String bContent = getFileContent(bfile);
        String myString = aContent.replace("java rulez", bContent);
        System.out.println("New content: ");
        System.out.println(myString);
        afile.delete();//delete old file
        writeFile(myString);//I replace the file by writing a new one with new content
    }
}

public static void writeFile(String myString) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/home/mtataje/a.txt")));
    bw.write(myString);
    bw.close();
}

public static String getFileContent(File f) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

    String line;
    StringBuffer sa = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       sa.append(line);
       sa.append("\n");
    }   
    br.close();
    return sa.toString();
}
```

I've just separated the method to avoid reading the file two times in the same block of code. I hope it could help you or at least, give you a hand with your requirement. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, with this I can copy the content from b.txt to a.txt but when I open the file a.txt there were no changes in it ...only in the console it is displaying the replaced content but the actual file is not getting saved. Any idea?

Comment: I modified the code in order to give you a way in which you could save the changes you made in the replacement. Best regards.